# After updating Intelij getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG

Tags: java, android, gradle, testng, appium

After updating intelij i cannot run anymore testng.xml.
If i run my tests as a separate Class it works fine and runs. But if i run it as a suite Testng.xml i got error.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Didea.testng.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/testng/lib/testng-plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/testng/lib/jcommander.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -port 63142 -usedefaultlisteners false -socket63143 @w@/private/var/folders/jq/g93n6rmj0xv6ccklv2l2xgs86xx4fm/T/idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp /private/var/folders/jq/g93n6rmj0xv6ccklv2l2xgs86xx4fm/T/idea_testng.tmp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Gradle configuration:

```
group 'ao-core-android'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Test.class" // whatever Ant pattern matches your test class files
}

test {
    useTestNG {
        suites 'testng.xml'
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:4.0.0'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.1'
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'externalLibs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('./lib-test-tools-1.4.0.jar')
}
```

It highlights the

```
test {
    useTestNG {
        suites 'testng.xml'
    }
}
```

in build.gradle.
And gives message :

```
test' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)' less... (⌘F1) 
This inspection reports assignments with incompatible types
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643424/noclassdeffounderror-org-testng-testng)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue 'Anton Anton' reported when I ran a particular unit test. However, this didn't happen when I ran the entire suite with `mvn clean test`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: org/test/TestNG
```

I came across this [blog post in the IntelliJ Community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206597869-Cannot-launch-NGTest-runner-in-IntelliJ-IDEA-2016-1) which did work for me.

> "I got it to work by selecting "In whole project" (I had "In single
>   module" selected) under the Configuration tab in the TestNG "Run/Debug
>   Configurations."

Credits to Serge Baranov and Leonardo Hernandez.